# Calling a function when anything in the HTML body changes without using onclick or setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I have a HTML code as :

```
<body>

<div id = "mypage">

<svg>....</svg>
<div>Hello all, how are you?</div>
<img>........</img>


</div>

</body>
```

When I highlight any part on this page (highlighting "how are") a span is attached to this part in the body and the resulting code becomes:

```
<body>

<div id = "mypage">

<svg>....</svg>
<div>Hello all, <span class="highlight">how are</span> you?</div>
<img>........</img>


</div>

</body>
```

This means a change has occured in the HTML body. Now, when this happens I want to trigger a javascript function. i.e. the function should be called whenever any change in the body happens.

I know this can be done by running the function via setInterval and continuously checking for any changes. Can I avoid it and trigger the function just when any change occurs?

Comment: in your hightligh plugin set this event

Comment: You are looking for mutation listeners - have a look at [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or the deprecated [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)

Comment: I had a look at mutation observers but not too sure on how can i use it to detect any change in the body. Could you provide a snippet on how can it be written?

Comment: @Zofler - I use the following code in a Chrome extension that nukes ads on a particular site. The ads aren't present when the page is loaded and thus must be nuked when they appear. It appears to fit your needs. `window.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', onDomChangedFunc, false);`, where onDomChangedFunc will be called in the event of any changes.

Comment: @enhzflep: I tried using the following on document.ready as document.body.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){alert("hua")},false); However, it keeps on executing. How exactly should I be using it?

Comment: @Zofler - what do you mean by "it keeps on executing"? Does the alert not show? Does the function fire repeatedly, when you only want it once? Something else perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the function runs repeatedly, i.e. it keeps on alerting "hua". I want the function to trigger only when there is some change in the body.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this in your JS(Jquery is required).

```
$(body).change(function() {
    yourFunction();
});
```

Comment: It does not work, I had already tried this. I suppose, change doesnot work on DOM objects but only on elements

Comment: then try $("#mypage").change(function() {});
any way the change is happening inside the div with id mypage ryt..